# blazor: have dynamically generated components return data to parent

Tags: blazor

i am working on a document uploader, where the user can upload multiple documents. for each new documents he wants to upload, he must press the button:

```
@for(int i = 0; i <= AmountOfDocs; i++){
                <div>
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 20px" class="dividerLine"></div>
                    <QT_Tagger.Shared.Details.DocumentUploader />
                </div>
            }          
            <button @onclick=AddDocument style="margin-top: 20px" class="goodButton">weiteres Dokument hinzufügen</button>
```

pressing the button will attach another instance of the documentuploader component.

Now when the user is finished I need to retrieve all documents that are on these layouts. How can I return the data from the file upload inside my document uploader when i dont know how many layouts the user has created ?

thank you!

EDIT:

the document uploader looks like this:

```
    private async Task SingleUpload(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        await e.File.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(ms);
        var bytes = ms.ToArray();
        //do something with bytes
    }

<div style="margin-top: 10px; width: 80%" >

    <strong style="margin-top: 20px">Dokumenten-Titel</strong>
    <p>Zur Anzeige auf der Artikelseite</p>
      <input @bind="Title" style="margin-top: 10px;" type="text" maxlength="80" placeholder="Titel: z.B: Original Rechung 01.01.2020">
      <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
          <strong class="headlines_options">Art des Dokuments</strong>
          <select id="selectedOption" style="margin-top: 10px; color: black; font-size: 13px; max-width: 80%"  class="form-control" @bind="TypeOfResell">
            <option selected style="color: black; font-size: 13px" value="@DocumentTypes.Rechnung"><strong>Rechnung</strong></option>
            <option style="color: black; font-size: 13px" value="@DocumentTypes.Garantie"><strong>Garantie</strong></option>
            <option style="color: black; font-size: 13px" value="@DocumentTypes.Andere"><strong>Andere</strong></option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <InputFile OnChange="@SingleUpload" class="custom-input-file" />
</div>
```

Comment: Have the uploader within a service and log the number of calls to the method?  Without any sort of [mre] it's hard to add more detail.